# Navigation controller is not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have navigation controller after showing first VC. I am using perform segue for navigate from first vc to second page with `performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondVC", sender: nil)` and my sidebar is appearing. However, when I tried to go third page from First vc it is not navigating. So, I tried to use following code

```
let thirdVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "thirdVC") as! ThirdVC
navigationController?.pushViewController(thirdVC, animated: true)
```

It is working but my navigation bar is disappearing when I used above code. How can I go from first vc to third?

[image]

Comment: Did you mean navigation bar is disappearing?

Comment: Yes navigation bar is disappearing.

Comment: Are u Pushing from FirstVC ?? Try Adding navigation controller to the first VC and push to any VC you want ..

Comment: Yes I am trying to push from first vc. But I do not want to see users side menu in my first vc?

Comment: What do you mean by users side menu?

Comment: I mean user should not see nav bar in the first vc.

Comment: @AtalayAsa show your side menu view.

Comment: You can hide nav bar in firstVC using this         navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
let thirdVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "thirdVC") as! ThirdVC
navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false  
//Make sure navigation controller should be there
navigationController?.pushViewController(thirdVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: If user press go to next page it is going to second vc. If user presses go to third page in the first execution of program do that code works?

Comment: Yes, if navigation controller is there.

Comment: Do you mean shall I add navigation controller into my first view controller?

Comment: Or present the navigation controller if you don’t have  navigation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165413/discussion-between-suryakantsharma-and-atalay-asa).